# How to keep 'content' field having max height of the window

Tags: html, css

Here's a example view and codes of what I'm getting stuck with:

https://codepen.io/kenmikanmi/pen/RwwYaEE

I want to expand `content` field with navy background so that white space disappears. Could you tell me how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Please include a [mre] **in the question itself**, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like a page with `<>` on it) to do so.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for your advice, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.content {
    height: 100vh;   /* instead of 100% try put 100vh */
 }
```

Comment: I would go with "min-height", if the content would ever expand beyond the screen height, like if the page is being watched on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {margin: 0;}
```

The height is inherent from the parents height if you use percentage heights.